# Cursor using QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am creating a C++ indexer that has the following cursor, which needs to be open for a long period of time, as it continuously times out.

I am aware there is the following option for cursor: `QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT`

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/Bytes.html

Though I am not sure how to use this in my C++ code below.

How do I add this option?

```
ScopedDbConnection conn("localhost");
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = conn -> query("test.collection", BSON("Levels" << 3));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this line.

```
auto_ptr cursor = conn -> query("test.collection", BSON("Levels" << 3),
                                0, 0, NULL, QueryOption_NoCursorTimeout);
```

It works on my machine. Hope it helps a bit.